# iterating through each h2 and append their values to another set of divs in order

Tags: jquery

I have a question.

How would i iterate through each h2 in their div, grab their text value and appending that to the other set of divs in the order that they appear on the other side?

i could use eq or something and go through each one but this isn't ideal as the number of divs at any given time could be more or less and i'll only have to go back and adjust the js to adjust for the number of divs.

There is no js i've done yet in this example just because i'm not sure how to approach this.

Any help is appreciated.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u2VY5/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `.eq` is your only choice, but it does not make your code inflexible:

```
var $divs = $('.wrap-two div.item');

$('.wrap h2').each(function(index) {
    $divs.eq(index).text($(this).text());
});

// or alternatively:

var $h2s = $('.wrap h2');

$('.wrap-two div.item').text(function(index) {
    return $h2s.eq(index).text();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2VY5/1/)

Additional `div`s will be just left empty and too few `div`s are not a problem either. `.eq` will always return a jQuery object, even if an element with that index does not exist. The call to `.text` will then just be silently ignored.

Or do you want to always have as many `div`s as `h2`s?

Comment: I'll always have as many div's as h2's, i've made sure of this. Your first iteration though worked out perfectly for my situation and what i wanted to accomplish. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also `clone()` the first list to the second, as they share the same `.item` class:

```
$('.wrap .item').clone().appendTo('.wrap-two');​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/u2VY5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/u2VY5/3/

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn1').on('click' , function(){
        var data = $('.wrap div h2');
        var target = $('.wrap-two div');

        $.each(data, function(i){
           $(target[i]).append('h2').text($(this).text());
        });

    });
});​
```

Comment: You don't have to append new `h2`s if you are immediately overwriting them with `.text`. `$(target[i]).text($(this).text());` produces the exact same result.